# Facing difficulty while installing pyenchant in python 3.6(windows 7)

Tags: python, pyenchant

I am unable to install pyenchant library in python 3.6. I tried to install it using pip install pyenchant command but it didn't work. [image: Error description]

Comment: You can try `pip install -U pyenchant  ` command.

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599004/problems-with-pyenchant-centos-el-capitan) They have a similar issue on a different OS but I believe its relevant here. You need to fix the dependency issue with the `enchant` C library that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having 64 bit Python installed.
Currently there is no 64 bit version of pyenchant.
The download [page](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/download.html) for pyenchant installer and wheel file also has 32 bit platform versions only.

For 64 bit, you have to build pyenchant from the source.

Instead it's much easier to install 32 bit version of latest Python (3.6.4 as of Jan 18) and pip install pyenchant.